# OpenGL ES on Iphone simulator

Tags: objective-c, opengl-es

i just started to learn it and i'm checking some tutorials to begin with it. I have played with OpenGL and C++ a few months ago and now i decided to try it on iphone, but i'm having a problem after this line code:

```
- (void)drawFrame
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();
}
```

It says:

Terminating in response to SpringBoard's termination.

Why is that? Do i forgot something?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the above code. If you need some help, I used [these excellent tutorials](http://www.71squared.com/iphone-tutorials/) on using OpenGL on the iPhone. Maybe they can help you too! Hope that Helps!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using OpenGL ES 1.1 or 2.0? In 2.0 `glLoadIdentity()` does not exist anymore check the [OpenGL ES 2.0 man pages](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/) for what functions are in 2.0.